# Kivy/pyjnius: get android.app.Application object of my app

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

Testflight api needs pointer to `android.app.Application` object for API methods like this:

```
TestFlight.takeOff(this, "your-token-***-***-***")
```

how can I get it for my kivy `App` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm  sherlock!

```
from jnius import autoclass
    PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
    application = PythonActivity.getApplication()
```

`application` contents wrapped by jnius `android.app.Application` instance.